# Problem starting phpMyAdmin in XAMPP

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a problem starting phpMyAdmin in XAMPP. Do I need to make any changes in the config files or should I change some port numbers?

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: MySQL server is stopped, therefore PhpMyAdmin is not able to work. Can you start MySQL server in XAMPP manually?

Comment: Yeah same problem here,I am also not able to start mysql server from the xampp control panel or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had previously installed mysql-workbench and had completely forgotten about it, hence the mysql server and phpmyadmin was not starting. So, Please be sure to uninstall any other server or ide before installing xampp, also remember to remove the configuration files of the previous server or ide. This worked for me, hopes work for others too.